# jEditable is taking only one id

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jeditable, in-place-edit

Alright. I'm new to jEditable. Let me explain the issue i'm having with jEditable.

I have this simple table in my database -

```
id  car        make 
1   panamera   porsche  
2   italia     ferraris 
3   avantador  lamborghini  
4   slk        mercedes
```

And i'm gonna echo this table in a while loop and below is the code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM inplace LIMIT 0, 6";    
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die ('Query couldn\'t be executed');  
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
?>

$(function() {
$(".items").editable("handler.php", { 
submitdata : {userid: "<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>"},
indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
tooltip   : "Doubleclick to edit...",
event     : "click",
onblur    : "submit",
name : 'newvalue',
id   : 'elementid',

}); 
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<ul>
<?php  
$query = "SELECT * FROM inplace LIMIT 0, 6";    
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Query couldn\'t be executed');  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo '<li class="items" id="car">'.$row['car'].'</li>';
echo '<li class="items" id="make">'.$row['make'].'</li>'; 
}

?>
</ul>
```

In the above code, i'm passing `newvalue`(user edited) and `elementid`(car or make) in the jeditable script. And i also need one more identifier which helps identify the correct database id to update. So i'm trying to pass the database id in `submitdata : {userid: "<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>"}`. I'm not sure if that method is correct.

And below is the update query in "handler.php" file -

```
require("db.php");

function fail($msg) {
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
die($msg);
}

$id = (int)@$_POST['userid'];

$field = @$_POST['elementid'];

$allowed_fields = array('car','make');
if (!in_array($field, $allowed_fields)) fail('Invalid or missing field.', 404);
$newvalue =  $_POST['newvalue'];
$query = "UPDATE inplace SET `$field`='$newvalue' WHERE id=$id"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo $newvalue;
```

So the issue here is, this `submitdata : {userid: "<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>"}` is passing only 1st id. That means its passing only one id. So even if you edit `italia` or `avantador` which belongs to ids 2 and 3 respectively, it updates 1st id. When i echo the query, whichever car you edit, it always reads as `UPDATE inplace SETcar='volante' WHERE id=1`. When i directly write 2 or 3 or 4 in the submitdata, it updates correctly. Its passing only one id. Someone suggested me to use like `id="car-'.$row['id'].'"` and then explode it and then use foo and stuff. I tried using it but didnt work for me. Looking for a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom attribute in your `<li>` tags containing the id number. Then in your jQuery, you just grab that value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

   $("li.items").each(function(index) {

      $(this).editable("handler.php", { 
         submitdata : {userid: $(this).attr('carid')},
         indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
         tooltip   : "Doubleclick to edit...",
         event     : "click",
         onblur    : "submit",
         name : 'newvalue',
         id   : 'elementid',
      });

   }); 

});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<ul>

<?php  
  $query = "SELECT * FROM inplace LIMIT 0, 6";    
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Query couldn\'t be executed');  
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo '<li class="items" carid="'.$row['id'].'" id="car">'.$row['car'].'</li>';
     echo '<li class="items" carid="'.$row['id'].'" id="make">'.$row['make'].'</li>'; 
  }
?>

</ul>
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this and i'm not 100% sure on the jQuery syntax.

**[EDIT]** I just changed it around to *hopefully* work using the `$(this)` selector to reference each specific `<li>`.

Comment: cillosis- I tried ur answer. But when i echo the query, its reading as UPDATE inplace SET `car`='panamera' WHERE id=0. Id is reading as 0.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't test it. It probably has to do with `$(this).attr("carid")`. I'm not sure if that's the correct selector to get the value. It should be similar though.

Comment: Do i need to change anything in my update query when i use $(this).attr("carid") in submitdata?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. It's submitting an ID number which is the same thing you were doing before. The rest of your code should  be unaffected. I wish I could offer more help on whether that jQuery selector is right though...

Comment: I'll be thankful if u help me solve this! Trying to solve this since a month! :)

Comment: @newbiewebb See corrections I made after some research, hopefully that works.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code that is writing out the id

```
submitdata : {userid: "<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>"},
```

will only run on the server, and only run once, so all submits will only use that one value.

cillosis has one solution to your problem.

Comment: Toby-  I tried cillosis's answer. But when i echo the query, its reading as UPDATE inplace SET car='panamera' WHERE id=0. Id is reading as 0. Do i need to change anything in my update query when i use $(this).attr("carid") in submitdata?